# Converting string into list of every two numbers in string

Tags: python-3.x, string, list

A string = `1 2 3 4`

Program should return = `[[1,2],[3,4]]`
in python

I want the string to be converted into a list of every two element from string

Answer (score 2):

You could go for something very simple such as:

```
s = "10 2 3 4 5 6 7 8"
l = []
i = 0
list_split_str = s.split()  # splitting the string according to spaces
while i < len(s) - 1:
    l.append([s[i], s[i + 1]])
    i += 2
```

This should output:

```
[['10', '2'], ['3', '4'], ['5', '6'], ['7', '8']]
```

You could also do something a little more complex like this in a two-liner:

```
list_split = s.split()  # stripping spaces from the string
l = [[a, b] for a, b in zip(list_split[0::2], list_split[1::2])]
```

The slice here means that the first list starts at index zero and has a step of two and so is equal to `[10, 3, 5, ...]`. The second means it starts at index 1 and has a step of two and so is equal to `[2, 4, 6, ...]`. So we iterate over the first list for the values of `a` and the second for those of `b`.

[zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) returns a list of tuples of the elements of each list. In this case, `[('10', '2'), ('3', '4'), ('5', '6'), ...]`. It allows us to group the elements of the lists two by two and iterate over them as such.

This also works on lists with odd lengths.
For example, with `s = "10 2 3 4 5 6 7 "`, the above code would output:

```
[['10', '2'], ['3', '4'], ['5', '6']]
```

disregarding the 7 since it doesn't have a buddy.

Comment: s = " 10 1 3 1"    it returns [[1,0],[1,3]]   i.e "10" gets splitted too HELP!!

Comment: @RatndeepKaushal Thank you for bringing this case to my attention. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution if the numbers exact length is divisible by 2

```
def every_two_number(number_string):
    num = number_string.split(' ')
    templist = []
    if len(num) % 2 == 0:
        for i in range(0,len(num),2):
            templist.append([int(num[i]),int(num[i+1])])
    return templist

print(every_two_number('1 2 3 4'))
```

you can remove the `if` condition and enclosed the code in `try` and `except` if you want your string to still be convert even if the number of your list is not divisible by 2

```
def every_two_number(number_string):
    num = number_string.split(' ')
    templist = []
    try:
        for i in range(0,len(num),2):
            templist.append([int(num[i]),int(num[i+1])])
    except:
        pass
    return templist

print(every_two_number('1 2 3 4 5'))
```